# Finding a conformal map from the intersection of two regions to a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I'm trying to solve a problem which asks me to find a conformal mapping from the intersection of $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z-i|< \sqrt2$  with $|z+i|>\sqrt2\}$ onto the open unit disk.

I'm really new to these and I'm a bit lost because this doesn't resemble the examples I've seen so far.

Obviously the disk and the other region intersect at $±1$, but I have no idea how to go about using this to find the result.

As I said, I haven't really done many examples of conformal maps so I'd really appreciate if you could help walk me through this example.

Comment: @MartinR sorry, I realised I'd made a mistake - the second inequality should actually have been $>\sqrt2$ instead of $<$, and I assumed that was such a fundamental difference it merited a new question. Thanks so much for answering it though - it definitely did help with my understanding regardless.

Comment: I'm really sorry - I'm new to the site and didn't realise that was the appropriate thing to do. It won't happen again!

Comment: @MartinR I've tried applying the same approach to the newer problem but I can't see how to do it - I can't seem to work out what sector the area would map to. Would you be able to help a little more? Again, I'm really sorry for deleting it like that!

Comment: You asked this question here [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059919/42969).